# Tool tip shows after click, how do I get it to hide after a short delay?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using [react-tooltip](https://github.com/wwayne/react-tooltip) to show a 'Copied!' tool-tip adjacent to a "Copy URL" button. I can get the tool tip to show on click with the code below, but it will only hide after a delay if I click the button again.

```
<CopyToClipboard text={viewState.copyUrl}>
    <RaisedButton
        label="Copy URL"
        primary={true}
        data-tip
        data-event='click'
        data-for='copyToClipboard'
        onClick={viewState.copyClick}
        style={{ width: '150px' }} />
</CopyToClipboard>
<ReactTooltip id='copyToClipboard' delayHide={1000}>
    <p>Copied!</p>
</ReactTooltip>
```

Any thoughts on how I can get this to hide?